# Compilation error while getting error number in c code

Tags: c

I'm trying to use strerror_r to get the error from the socket function ,but the code is not compiling .i'm getting the error as `invlaid conversion from char * to an int`. i have included `errorno.h`and `string.h` in my code and i'm using eclipse ide running on ubuntu 12.04 .The code is as below.

```
int err;
char buffer[50];
result=connect(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

   if(result==0)
   {
      printf("\n connect success ");

   }
   else if(result==-1)
   {
       err = strerror_r(errno,buffer,50);// error in place 
       printf("%d",err);
   }
```

Comment: `strerror_r` is returning a `char *` not `int`.

Comment: "i have included `errorno.h`and `string.h` in my code" -- Then please show us code with those `#include` directives. It's always better to show (copy-and-pasted) code than to describe what your code looks like. (If you really included `errorno.h`, you would have gotten an error message; it's `errno.h`.) And please copy-and-paste the error message rather than re-typing it. Seemingly subtle nuances can be important. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default the GNU version of strerror_r() is used, which has the following signature:

```
char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
```

You can try to undefine the `_GNU_SOURCE` macro in order to get the standard version of this routine. Something like:

```
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

It might be a good idea to isolate that into its own header file (like `xsi_strerror_r.h`) so that you can include it only where needed. Or even a wrapper function around strerror_r() so that undefining `_GNU_SOURCE` will have no other unintended effects. For example:

```
#ifndef XSI_STRERROR_R
#define XSI_STRERROR_R

#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>

int xsi_strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);

#endif
```

The above would be a header file (xsi_strerror_r.h). You then provide a simple implementation for xsi_strerror_r() in its own source file:

```
#include "xsi_strerror_r.h"
int xsi_strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen)
{
    return strerror_r(errnum, buf, buflen);
}
```

And then you only use xsi_strerror_r() in the rest of your code.

Comment: The `#ifdef` is unnecessary. `#undef` does nothing if the macro isn't already defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed.

Comment: @KeithThompson : yes keith but i came across is this function in linux  so wanted to try .i have been doing win32 programming which uses wgetlasterror to get socket function errors ,so wanted to check if there is an similar function out in linux .

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
Include <errno.h>
```

Should solve the problem

---

Note that the other reason for this error [According to docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r) might be that,

it returns **int on XSI-compliant system** and returns **char* on GNU specific system**.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r, `strerror_r` can either return a `char *` or `int`.  The `char *` version says it's GNU-specific, so if you're using GNU, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: i saw a place where the function prototype returned an int . Now how to get the error number ?

Comment: @SanthoshPai, I'm not sure what you're asking - the error number is passed as an argument to strerror_r.

Comment: @SanthoshPai Why not just `printf("Error: %d\n",errno);` then?